# Is AlphaZero open source?

Tags: alphazero, development, open-source

There are a lot of fake AlphaZero projects on [GitHub](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GitHub). While I was googling if it was open-source, the answer in most places is *yes*, but I couldn’t find it anywhere. Is there a link to where the code is?

Comment: You might want to look at [Leela Chess Zero](https://lczero.org/) which is free and open-source.

Comment: Is Leela stronger than Stockfish?

Comment: Not yet as far as I know, but it is similar to AlphaZero in the sense that it learns chess without any knowledge except the basic rules.

Comment: Possibly relevant to OP:  DeepMind's [AlphaZero Resources webpage](https://deepmind.com/research/open-source/alphazero-resources)

Comment: [Agadmator](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cAIhA88SMuk) [has](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SFn9HvzkOqI) [covered](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K0gBybDFcMg) [Leela Chess Zero](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g08qtNIoJhM), but not Leela vs. [AlphaZero](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mOqmLYlFdBo) [as](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QEylXLEJ-Eg) [far](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SRRu8H8025E) [as](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wui0YweevtY) [I](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vq0uTq0Z3Xk) [know](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p393G67bfNM).

Comment: @VarunW: LeelaZero is stronger than AlphaZero was, and it was briefly on par with the then latest Stockfish. But current latest Stockfish is again stronger.

Comment: @PeterMortensen Leela has never played AlphaZero, so it's not surprising.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, AlphaZero isn't open source.

Comment: <citation needed> ;-)

Comment: Easier said than done, my Google Fu is strong and I wasn't able to find any info except this German: https://www.chess-international.com/?p=18146 I.e. even if you could DL it, you would need a special supercomputer.

Comment: I follow engine chess closely and am 100% certain this is the right answer. It is why AlphaZero has never competed in the standard chess engine tournaments, and why Leela Chess Zero started from scratch instead of from AlphaZero's base code. I do not have a source though, because it is common knowledge.

Comment: Even the object code isn't available to the public, is it? Matthew Sadler was temporarily given special access to AlphaZero to write his book *Game Changer* but my impression was that was a very special exception.

Comment: @TimothyChow yeah, AlphaZero is private. If you want access to AlphaZero you need to ask DeepMind.